# Rebind 'q' key in Emacs Dired to the command 'kill-this-buffer'

Tags: key-bindings

If I press 'q' in Dired this buries the current buffer. I would prefer to have 'q' kill the buffer. Hence, I would like to bind the command "kill-this-buffer" to 'q' in Dired. Is this possible and advisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possible?:  Yes.

Is this advisable?:  Emacs is meant to be configurable and custom tailored to the needs of each particular user.  There is no disadvantage that I am aware of to rebinding the "q" key to something that the O.P. finds more useful.

```lisp
(require 'dired)
(define-key dired-mode-map "q" 'kill-this-buffer)
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be: `(with-eval-after-load 'dired (define-key dired-mode-map "q" 'kill-this-buffer))`

Comment: "Is this advisable?" The answer is: "probably not" . 'quit-window is bound to "q" and should be left as is. My suggestion to OP is to define another key to 'kill-this-buffer, for instance, the letter "K" is available.